# Что такое стеки и очереди?

Tags: c++, очередь, стек

Учусь на втором курсе, программирование, C++. Расскажите, пожалуйста, о стеках. Как пишется программа?

Comment: Доьавлю, что очень хорошая книга по вашему вопросу - "Абстракция данных и решение задач на C++. Стены и зеркала". Каррано Ф. М., Причард Д. Д.

Comment: да! поддерживаю, это отличная книга по структурам данных, обязательно читайте её

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Стек - структура данных с доступом к элементам по принципу LIFO (Last In First Out - Последний пришел - первый вышел). Данные добавляются в начало (конец, кому как удобно), оттуда же и извлекаются. Для реализации данной структуры достаточно иметь лишь две функции и указатель на верхушку:

```
push(item); //добавляет данные в стек
pop(); //извлекает последний элемент
```

Очередь - структура данных с доступом к элементам по принципу FIFO (First In First Out - Первый пришел - Первый вышел). Данные добавляются в конец, а извлекаются из начала. Для быстрого добавления и извлечения данных понадобится два указателя, один на начало, очереди, второй на ее конец. Для работы с очередью используются функции:

```
enqueue(item); //добавляет новый элемент в очередь
dequeue(); //извлекает элемент из очереди
```

Для работы с указателями в C++ вам необходимо ознакомиться, например, с [данной статьей](http://translated.by/you/a-beginner-s-guide-to-pointers/into-ru/) (одна из первых в поиске).

Затем, вам необходимо создать элемент данных вашего стека (очереди). Например:

```
struct data {
    int p;
    int c;
}
```

После этого обзавестись ячейкой стека. Например:

```
struct element {
 data element_data;
 element *next; //указатель на следующий элемент
}
```

Указатель на следующий элемент необходим дабы наши данные в стеке (очереди) имели некоторую последовательность и были как-то связаны между собой.

После этого пишете необходимые функции, обзаводитесь указателями на начало (и конец, при необходимости). Например для push():

```
//somewhere in the code
element *top; //инициализируется в NULL
//...
void push(data newData) {
 //создаем нашу структуру element и указатель на нее
 element *newElement = new element();
 //element_data = newData
 element->element_data = newData;
 //next = top - здесь мы и задаем связку между двумя элементами стека
 element->next = top;
 //top = указателю на нашу структуру
 top = newElement;
}
```

Все остальное по аналогии. На C++ давненько я не кодил (проверить негде), поэтому прошу заранее прощения всех гуру, поправьте если где напортачил.

Comment: Ремарка: В C++ нет необходимости самому реализовывать эти структуры данных. Они уже есть в стандартной библиотеке. <a href=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/>std::queue</a> - для очереди и <a href=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/>std::stack</a> - для стэка. При этом следует обратить внимание, что эти структуры реализуются через другие, нижележащие. Например, очередь - через дэк (то же самое, что и очередь, но возможно добавление/удаление элементов для обоих концов дэка)

Comment: Оно то да, но для общего то развития надо, тем более на втором курсе.

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее!!!

Comment: @Kollibry, не за что, чтобы принять ответ нажмите галочку около него.

Comment: Приведённый пример - работа со списком, стек немного иначе работает.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы описал стэк как упаковку с коллекцией монеток, уложеных в стопочку. С 1 до 10. Что бы получить доступ к 5, нужно снять 10, потом 9, 8, 7, 6 и только потом получим 5-ю. Ну это лично моё ИМХО, когда то мне было проще запомнить так. В остальном остаются только технические вопросы, и я не могу не согласится с **Dex**'ом...

Comment: обычно про стек говорят это стопка книг или тарелок. Т.е. помыли тарелку, положили её сверху (это push). Нужно вам покушать, взяли тарелку - это pop

Comment: Не могу не согласится)

Comment: Так вот оно че :)<br>
Получается если поднапрячься можно написать книгу по С++ для блондинок с абстракциями на тарелках, монетках и т.д. ^^

Comment: Еще один, как по мне, очень хороший пример стека - пружинный магазин (оружие). Последний вставленный патрон первым выстрелит.

Comment: причем если совпадут типы, и обязательно в ногу